# Save form data to .txt file

Tags: php, file-io

Is that possible?  I need to save first name, last name and email address to a simple .txt file and the best would be if each entry would be added into a new line, so I can use the .txt file in Open Office.

Comment: You have a history of off-topic or heavily downvoted questions and are at risk of losing your question-asking privileges. [You should read this before you post your next one.](http://s.tk/onhold)

Comment: `$content = file_get_contents('file.txt'); $content .= "$name $lastname $email \r\n"; file_put_contents('file.txt', $content); `>

Comment: It's normal here that every question gets downvoted. I don't really care about that.

Comment: In answer to your question. Yes it is possible.

Comment: Thanks, could you eventually make a jfiddle?

Answer (score 1):

```
$myfile = fopen($textfilepath.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR."filename.txt", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");

    $txt = "first Name : " .$value."\r\n";

    $txt .= "Last Name : " .$value."\r\n";

    fwrite($myfile, $txt);

    fclose($myfile);
```